# How to extract values from nested nodes with HtmlAgilityPack c#

Tags: c#

I have the following situation where I need to extract some text within a few nested divs using HtmlAgilityPack with c#

```
<div class = "content">
    <div data-type = "container">
        <div class = "level1">
            <div class = "level2">
                <span>some_text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the text i need to get is "some_text", I have tried everything but still cant get my head around this.

Comment: Have you tried to use XPath? You can execute an XPath query which will return the node that you are interested in.

Comment: Please show us that "everything" that you have tried. Right now you don't show any C# code at all.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code, I deleted it out of pure frustration, wasnt trying to get my code corrected anyway, just trying to get an answer for this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.Load("YOUR_HTML_FILENAME.html");

var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span");

string someText = string.Empty;

if (node != null)
    someText = node.InnerText; //result >> some_text
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer although if i have another <span> that is in a parent node above the span in the example I will get that <span> value